# check the WCF is availabe or not in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am trying to get the service from a website ,so i connect to the `webService` like this :

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(domainAddress+"/services/reportSRC.svc");
ChannelFactory<IReportSRC> factory = new ChannelFactory<IReportSRC>(binding, address);
IReportSRC channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

So but sometimes the service is not available .how can i check this ability ?i mean if the service is available i connect to it otherwise show the error `the service is not available`

Suppose i have a list that contains several services and a state ,if the service is available the state is true otherwise is false.

Comment: @MickyD you know i want to show to my user which service is available ,

Comment: @MickyD i don't say to write a program i want to clear the question .OK?

Comment: Just make a `Ping()` / `Nop()` method in your service and call it from your client proxy.  You can always put it on a different interface like `ISupportDiagnostics` and bind to a separate WCF endpoint

Comment: with BasicHttpBinding - only polling and/or call error handling is an option

Answer (score 0):

you can always use a try-catch block and call the method for testing purpose of your choice.

```
try
{
    serviceClient.AnyMethod();
}
catch
{
    //Service not available
}
```